# A round, plastic pinion in a lock?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, motors

I'm looking at a [teardown of a Masterlock](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MasterLock+1500EDBX+Teardown/14148). The guts look like this

[image]

What's strange to me is the black, plastic pinion that appears to be smooth and a strangely shaped cam:

[image]

Here's the cam magnified:

[image]

The motor doesn't seem to be encoded in anyway to prevent stall and the PCB only has one microswitch, but it's for the spring-loaded, shuttle-like metal piece rather than the cam. So I wonder how the motor knows when to stop without stalling. There doesn't seem to be a current shunt on the PCB either.

My take is that the square groove of the cam (top facing) faces down in the housing. The round groove on the right of the square groove is where the plastic pinion contacts. That leaves the two not-so-visible grooves facing the mat (ie those facing away from the housing). Does anyone know how the cam is turned? The bottom groove of the cam appears round, so it could probably grip on the black plastic "pinion". But then, if cam shaft is the axis of rotation, that round face can't be the contact face with the pinion.

Does anyone know how how the shaft is rotated or how the motor is encoded such that it won't stall?

I'll also magnify the black plastic pinion here:

[image]

Comment: The pinion+cam is probably part of a eight of a geneva drive.

Comment: What makes you think the motor doesn't stall? They may be just using it as a cheap rotary solenoid.

Comment: If the motor stalls, it'll overheat and burn down, right? Plus, I wonder how the pinion grips on the cam.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I'm not sure if it's like a Geneva drive. The drive wheel and the driven wheel rotate in reverse to each other. The first picture shows the lock state where the pin groove faces up. So for the cam to rotate the motor shaft needs to rotate anti clockwise. However, to unlock, the cam needs to rotate anti clockwise.

Comment: No, there are plenty of small motors that can be stalled without damage. Besides, do you hear the motor running freely when you operate the lock, or do you just hear a click?

Comment: it's easy enough to add a current limiting resistor in series to avoid the burn up.

Comment: @DaveTweed I don't actually own one; I'm using looking at teardown photos.

Comment: Have you tried measuring the current through and voltage across the motor around the time you expect it might be stalling? And have you had a look inside the motor to see if it has any subtle  echanisms that might turn it off under over-torque or similar?

Comment: There are several ways it might work, but without more details an answer could only hypothesize on actual mechanism in use.